# How to evaluate this limit by using the knowledge of the Riemann Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{n^2+i^2}$$ solvable by using the knowledge of Riemann Integral. Precisely, can we find a special partition such that makes it become an Integral problem?

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{nk}{n^2+k^2}=n \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k/n}{1+(k/n)^2}\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n \times  \int_{1}^{1} \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx =\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partition $\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\dotsb,\frac{i}{n},\dotsb,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}.$
Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2+i^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(\frac{i}{n})}{1+(\frac{i}{n})^2}(\frac{1}{n})=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx<\infty$$ which implies
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2+i^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}(n) ({\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2+i^2}})=\infty.$$

Comment: Where did your $n^2$ go in the first step?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake.

Comment: Yep, so if the limit without $n^2$ is <$\infty$, then multiplying by $n$ would make $\lim \to \infty$, shown in the answer below.

Comment: I edit it just similar to the answer from @Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc. Thank you.